# (how) can one swap two entire arrays - of equal size and type - in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swap

```
var arrayOne = [UInt64](repeating: 0, count: 1 << 16)
var arrayTwo = [UInt64](repeating: 0, count: 1 << 16)
```

In the program both arrays are filled with differing
values. Then the entire arrays need to be swapped in as little clock cycles as possible.

```
(arrayOne[], arrayTwo[] = arrayTwo[], arrayOne[]) won’t work.
```

What is the simple and fast way to do it?

Comment: Why are you saying `(arrayOne, arrayTwo) = (arrayTwo, arrayOne)` won't work?

Comment: What's your use case here? Who owns the two arrays? Note that arrays are value types, so swapping their contents results in holders of previous references to point to the outdated (non-swapped) arrays.

Comment: Results of calculations performed on elements of one[] are stored in two[], then it is to be repeated in opposite direction. (like swapping pointers). Reason: memory constraints; actual array is 1<<28 elements; minimizing number of load and store operations/ clock cycles.

Comment: Seems you need both low memory usage and low CPU usage, but most of the times these are exclusive, you usually use more memory to make your algorithms faster, or the other way around, use more CPU is you have memory constraints.  To address both, we need more details about your problem domain. Maybe the code that generates the data can be changed to avoid the need for swapping, for example.